# Java: synchronized(Object) and RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, exception, synchronized

I have this problem:

I have a few threads which access one object with `synchronized(Object) { ... }`

But sometimes this exception is raised:

execute: `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`

Why? And what should I do with it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an Executor anywhere in here?  I've run into that when my Executor won't take the work, for whatever reason (queue is full, etc).

Answer (score 2):

That exception is meant to be raised by `Executor.execute` - you certainly shouldn't be seeing it just by accessing objects in a synchronized block.

Have a look at the rest of the stack trace to work out exactly where it's occurring, and look at the message to see if that gives you any more information about why you're getting it. As Todd commented, it would usually be due to something like a full work queue.

For example, `ThreadPoolExecutor` will throw this exception if the queue is uses to buffer tasks to be run refuses to accept more items. This usually indicates that your system is overloaded, or you've misconfigured the executor.